# POST запрос в node.js

Tags: node.js, sql-server, post, express

Добрый день. Начал недавно разбираться с node.js и express. Делаю POST к mssql 2012 запрос с клиента:

```js
var newUser = {
            'name': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputName').val(),
            'url': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUrl').val(),
            'date': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputDate').val(),
        }
   
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: newUser,
            url: '/users/adduser',
            dataType: 'JSON'
        }).done(function(response)
```

Но не получаю никакой информации в маршруте. Проверяю это с помощью console.log. Делаю приложение на express и с npm модулем mssql. С GET-запросом проблем не возникает. Обработчик POST-запроса:

```js
router.post('/adduser', function(req, res) {
     sql.connect(config, function(err) {
         if (err) console.log(err);
         console.log(req.name);
         console.log(req.url);
         console.log(req.date);    
          
         // запрос
         var request = new sql.Request();
         request.query('INSERT into Data.......',function(err){
             if (err) console.log(err);
            //
           //
           //
           //
           //
           //
         });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечу сам на свой вопрос) В целом это, наверное, стандартные ошибки новичков в node.js и express. Моя главная ошибка была в том, что я не использовал bodyParser, который не входит в стандартный пакет express и его надо устанавливать отдельно. Чтобы добавить параметр в запрос [используется](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#input-name-type-value)

```js
request.input();
```

Теперь мой код выглядит так:

```
router.post('/addrecord', function(req, res) {
var name = req.body.name;
var url = req.body.url;
var date = req.body.date;
sql.connect(config, function(err) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
        // запрос
    var request = new sql.Request();
    request.input('name', name);
    request.input('url', url);
    request.input('date', sql.Date, date);
    request.query("INSERT into Data (name,url,date) VALUES(@name,@url,@date)", function(err) {
      .........
    });
});
});
```